# MVC LabelFor and CheckBoxFor displaying label on top of checkbox instead of next to it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following Razor code. What it's doing (which must be the default) is displaying the label on top of the checkbox instead of next to it, which is preventing an error message from being displayed there as well in the case of error. How can I display the label next to the checkbox?

```
<div class="row">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Is13)
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Is13)
      @Html.ValidationMessage("REGISTER_O")
</div>
```

Comment: This is not "the default" behavior.  Obviously, you have some CSS which in your app which is having this side-effect and you need to figure out what is causing it.  Use your browser developer tools (F12) to find out what CSS is affecting it.

Comment: are you using bootstrap? if you're using ASP.NET's MVC 5 Template, the answer is probably yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the `display: inline-block;` css property to the label.

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Is13)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Is13)
    @Html.ValidationMessage("REGISTER_O")
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    .row label { display: inline-block; }
</style>
```

Update - apparently MVC may cause generated labels to have a `display:block;` property set, so setting the label to `display:inline` should fix that.

Update 2 -
As others have said, this is not typically the default behavior, so you must have other CSS (Bootstrap?) that can be affecting your styling.

You can try adding the `!important` rule to your css definition. Use caution when using this, as it will override any other styles for the properties you use it on, which can potentially cause headaches later on.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .row label { display: inline-block !important; }
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding !important to your style? This would override any other 'display' styles for the specified selector, so you should be careful when doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap you can do this

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Is13) Is 13
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Is13)
    </label>
</div>
```

example from: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You can also just swap the order of the label and checkbox.

```
<div class="row">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Is13)
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Is13)
      @Html.ValidationMessage("REGISTER_O")
</div>
```